# Use parent module as dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have multi-module java library with some classes, configs, and so on in structure like this:

```
/common-parent
--/common-a
--/common-b
/module-a
/module-b
```

`module-a` needs import only module `common-a` but in `module-b` I need import modules `common-a` and `common-b`.

Is possible to import both as one dependency? I tried import parent module `common-parent` into `module-b` but I still cannot see classes in these modules. `Common-parent` module use pom packaging and his sub-modules use default jar packaging. Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work this way, the parent-child relation only does one thing: The child inherits configuration from the parent. If you declare the parent as dependency, you only depend on the parent, not on modules defined in its pom, nor on children which inherit from the parent.

In order for this to work, you need some module which declares a dependency on common-a and common-b, and depend on that.